# SQLAlchemy: get relationships from a db.Model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I need to get a list of a model's properties which are actually relationships (that is, they were created by `relationship()`).

Say I have a model `Foo` in a `models`:

```
class Thing(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(...)
    bar_id = db.Column(...)
    foo_id = db.Column(...)
    foo = db.relationship('Foo')
    bar = db.relationship('Bar')
```

Later on, I want to take `models.Thing` and get a list of relationship-properties, that is `['foo', 'bar']`.

Currently I'm checking every attribute indicated by `dir(models.Thing)` that happens to be of type `sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute` for the class of its `property` attribute — which can be either a `ColumnProperty` or `RelationshipProperty`. This does the job but I was wondering if there's another way.

I could probably just find all attributes ending in `_id` and derive the relationship name, but this could break for some cases.

How about setting a `__relationships__ = ['foo', 'bar']`?

Or is there something built into SQLAlchemy to help me out?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There is indeed - take a look at [`sqlalchemy.inspection.inspect`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/inspection.html). Calling `inspect` on a mapped class (for example, your `Thing` class) will return a [`Mapper`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper), which has a [`relationships`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper.relationships) attribute that is `dict` like:

```
from sqlalchemy.inspection import inspect

thing_relations = inspect(Thing).relationships.items()
```

Comment: is there an easy way to see the "Foo" and "Bar" as well?

Comment: Not sure what you mean - worth making a new question and linking to this question for context.

Comment: Edited to add `.items()` because I found myself with a sqlalchemy.util._collections.ImmutableProperties and it was not very helpful (as classes go I mean, it doesn't print). He wanted a list.

Answer (score 27):

Instead of using `inspect` you can also use

`model.__mapper__.relationships`

Answer (score 15):

You just need to use the `inspect` module from `sqlalchemy`

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect

i = inspect(model)
i.relationships
```

If you need the class of each referred model you can do:

```
referred_classes = [r.mapper.class_ for r in i.relationships]
```