# SQLAlchemy; getting list of related tables/classes

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Say I have a `Thing` class that is related to some other classes, `Foo` and `Bar`.

```
class Thing(Base):
FooKey = Column('FooKey', Integer,
                       ForeignKey('FooTable.FooKey'), primary_key=True)
BarKey = Column('BarKey', Integer, ForeignKey('BarTable.BarKey'), primary_key=True)
foo = db.relationship('Foo')
bar = db.relationship('Bar')
```

I want to get a list of the classes/tables related to `Thing` created by my `relationships()` e.g. `[Foo, Bar]`. Any way to do this?

This is a closely related question:
[SQLAlchemy, Flask: get relationships from a db.Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206818/sqlalchemy-flask-get-relationships-from-a-db-model). That identifies the string names of the relationships, but not the target classes.

Context:
I'm building unit tests for my declarative base mapping of a SQL database. A lot of dev work is going into it and I want robust checks in place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `Mapper` as described in that other question gets you on the right path. As mentioned on the doc [[0]](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper.relationships), you will get a bunch of `sqlalchemy.orm.relationships.RelationshipProperty`, and then you can use `class_` on the `mapper` associated with each `RelationshipProperty` to get to the class:

```
from sqlalchemy.inspection import inspect
rels = inspect(Thing).relationships
clss = [rel.mapper.class_ for rel in rels]
```

Comment: you got it! all it took was from 

sqlalchemy.inspection import inspect
rels = inspect(Thing).relationships
clss = [rel.argument for rel in rels]

append your answer and ill award the accepted answer