# How to get relationships from one entity to the other entities in the legacy database?

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

How do I enter the name of an entity in the legacy database and get a list containing the names of the entities it relates to?

Comment: You might be looking for SQLAlchemy's `inspect`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21209747/5747944).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! But maybe I have not managed to be clear when my doubt. By using the indicated response, you can get the attribute that has the relationship, but does not say to which entity it is linked

Comment: it's in another answer on the same page. If you want to get the class to which relationship is linked... `.relationships` gives you a list of relationships... each of those will have the following attribute that shows the related class:  `.mapper.class_`